# Django: Unable to configure handler 'console'

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a simple logging definition in the settings.py file:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s',
        },
        'verbose': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatters': 'simple',
            'propagate': False
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'myapp': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG'
         },
    }
}
```

When I run my program, I get the error:

```
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'console'
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`propagate` is not an option for handlers but for loggers. So your configuration should be.

```
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple',
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'myapp': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': False
     },
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I even tried removing propagate from both the places and still doesn't work.

Comment: @conquester It is `formatter` not `formatters`. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I changed and tested your LOGGING dictionary bit by bit, the following version works

```
{
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'simple': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s',
    },
    'verbose': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple',
    }
},
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        "propagate": True
     },
}
```

}

There are three differences between `LOGGING` and the above dictionary:

1. In `LOGGING`, there is a key value pair `'propagate': False` in `LOGGING.handlers.console`. It was removed in the above dictionary
2. In `LOGGING.loggers`, the unique key is `'myapp'`. In the above dictionary, the `'myapp'` is replaced by an empty string `''`
3. In `LOGGING.loggers`, there is a key value pair `"propagate": False` in the unique sub dictionary. It was replaced by `"propagate": True`.

Hope it helps.